# How to set static IP address to a container running into a Swarm over a weave-overlay network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, weave

**TL;DR: bug present in Swarm `1.0.0`, solved in Swarm `1.1.0`.**

On a four swarm agents cluster, a custom overlay network is run with the [weave plugin](http://www.weave.works/products/weave-net/):

```
user@swarm-master:~$swarm-docker network create --driver weave --subnet 192.168.0.0/16 custom-weave
```

However, with this command and its output we can see an issue:

```
user@swarm-master:~$ swarm-docker run --rm -it --net=custom-weave --ip=192.168.0.5 debian:jessie bash -c "ip addr     show"
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    [ . . ]
74: ethwe0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1410 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:c2:9c:6c:c3:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/16 scope global ethwe0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ecc2:9cff:fe6c:c36c/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
76: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    [ . . ]
```

The user defined `--net` option is set as well as `--ip=192.168.0.5`. While the container is expected to have its `ethwe0` interface IP address set to **192.168.0.5**, it is actually set to **192.168.0.2**.

#### Question: What is wrong with this process?

Nothing, just a bug solved since the version `1.1.0`.

Comment: I have tried `--net` and `--ip` options for a manually created network with a  *bridge* driver that comes with docker and it was working perfectly (actually still is). Since this `--ip` is relatively new, maybe the weave plugin is not updated, or simply isn't handling this in the right way...

Comment: Did you try within swarm? As I tried within swarm with the default overlay it didn't work neither.

Comment: Nope, didn't try with swarm, just started 3 containers (in addition - I used `--add-host` for each of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [vieux](https://github.com/vieux) on this [GH issue](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1828), this is a bug in Swarm `1.0.0`. This bug has been solved in the Swarm `1.1.0`.